# no chip name specified; use "PICC18 --CHIPINFO"

Tags: c, pic18, xc8

I did a simple program to light a led.

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ 19660800
#define USE_AND_MASKS
#include <xc.h>
#include <pic18f46k22.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(void) {
    TRISA=0;
    PORTA=0;
    PORTA=0x5A;
    while (1)
    {   
    }
}
```

I use a PIC18F46k22 and a XC8 compiler. The issue is that when I compile the program the compiler gives the message ***no chip name specified; use "PICC18 --CHIPINFO"***

Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: `void main(void)`...shouln't it be `int main(void)`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh - No.  `void main(void)` is very common in microcontrollers where there's nowhere useful for main to return to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compile, add  `--chip=18f452` to your compilation flag.
That should do the trick.

Basically you need to tell your compiler what kind of chip you're willing to work with, since XC8 can build for different kinds of chip.

Have fun with thoses chips anyway !

Comment: I´m using MPLAB IDE v8.83 and I´m not sure where I should to add this command, In build options?

Thank you for your help and encouraged

Comment: I did not use MPLAB but i'd sugest you should look into the build option and for "compiler arguments", and then add the line i wrote. Here, look there for adding the option : https://microchip.wikidot.com/mplabx:configure-project-build-options